# Graph theory term and notation for "splitting" a point into more points

Tags: graph-theory, notation, terminology

Suppose $v$ is a vertex in a graph $G$.  Is there a name for the process of replacing $v$ with $d(v)$ (the degree of $v$) many vertices, one attached to each edge coming into $v$?

For instance if $V(K_3)=\{v_0,v_1,v_2\}$ are the vertices of the "triangle" graph, then doing my process at any one vertex would produce $P_3$, the path of length 3 (3 edges between 4 vertices).

What about going in the other direction, smashing vertices together?  Is there a name for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "**blowing up** the vertex", by analogy to [blowing up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_up) in algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an edge $e=\{u,v\}$ in a graph, then the process of "smashing" u and v is called a *contraction of the edge e*. The result of this contraction is a single vertex $x_{uv}$ which has exactly the same neighbours that $u$ and $v$ had in the original graph.

I don't know if there is a name for the "splitting" process, though.

Comment: If I had to come up with a name of the process of splitting, I'd call it "fragmentation". I'm posting this as a comment, though, and not as part of the answer, because there might already be an existing name.